# How to import ngModel into link funciton of directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, contenteditable

I have to access ngModel into my directives link function. Here is the code:

```
app.directive("contenteditable", function() {
    var directive = {};
    directive.require = ['^parentDirective','?ngModel'];
    directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        ngModel.someMethod(); // Gives method not found
    }
```

But I am not sure how to pass or access 'ngModel' from directive link function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're "requiring" an array of controllers, you will get an array of controllers back injected into your link function.

```
directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
    var ngModel = ctrls[1];
    ngModel.someMethod();
}
```

From [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile/#-require-):

> The require takes a string name (or array of strings) of the directive(s) to pass in. If an array is used, the injected argument will be an array in corresponding order.